# Trying to read bytes using fread but getting Segmentation Fault 11

Tags: c, file, byte

Im writing a string as bytes to a file and then want to read the binary code back as a string using strtol. I checked the the binary file and it contained the binary of the letter i included using xxd -b filename. However when i try to read it back and convert it to a string it gives a segmentation fault 11. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    FILE* fr = fopen("kot.bin", "wb+");
    size_t written = fwrite("n", 1, 1, fr);
    printf("written is: %zu\n", written);
    fclose(fr);

    FILE* fw = fopen("kot.bin", "rb");
    char * name;
    size_t red = 0;
    red = fread(name, 1, 1, fw);
    if (red==0) {
        printf("ur wrong\n");
    }
    printf("red: %zu\n", red);
    char c = (char) strtol(name, NULL, 2);
    printf("c: %c\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

I simply want to store one byte in buffer, use strtol to make it into a a character and print it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You neglected to allocate memory to read the byte into. I recommend `name = (char*)malloc(1);`.

Comment: @Beta that would make a splendid answer.

Comment: oh man. thanks for that. I thought there was something wrong with my use of strtol, I've never actually used it before. Although the segmentation fault is gone now, when i try to print c, it seems to be empty. Any ideas on why that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you neglected to allocate memory to read the byte into. I recommend:

```
name = (char*)malloc(1);
```

Second, your use of `strtol` makes no sense. You have a byte containing 'n'. Thi is *not* a null-terminated string, so I think that calling `strtol` on it will cause Undefined Behavior. But in any case 'n' is not a numeral, so `strtol` will return 0. You then cast the `long int` 0 to a `char`. Without looking it up, I don't know what character (if any) corresponds to the `long int` value 0, but it sure ain't 'n'. Do it this way:

```
printf("c: %c\n", *name);
```

Comment: Thanks. I was under the impression I had to use strtol to convert the contents of name to a string using strtol. I didn't know I could simply read it as a character. Thanks for that!